# Omnet++ uniform random number generation

Tags: omnet++

When I assign the result of a `intuniform(a,b)` function call to a number, it always results in the same value. For example:

```
val = intuniform(0,100);
```

`val` is always 44 for every run.

How can I manage that?

Answer (score 0):

Generating the same values by `OMNeT++` RNG is intentional behaviour. In order to manage generated sequence one can change [seed](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:config-sim:repeating-runs-with-different-seeds) or just add a repetition in `omnetpp.ini`.

Comment: Here, it is my `omnetpp.ini` file :                                                               `[General]
network = Network
num-rngs = 1
seed-set=${runnumber}`                                                                          `val` still does not change.  Any suggestion?

Comment: Set for example: `seed-set=23`.